# Stretch Row Table Layout Android

Tags: android, row

I want to stretch row equal to device screen as we are doing for the column in Table Layout in Android device.
Please help me and thanks in advance for doing this.

Comment: can you provide a sketch or mockup kind of design so that we people here come to know exactly about your doubt.

Comment: You need to accept answers that worked for you so that next time you ask questions - people don't hesitate to post answers!

Answer (score 12):

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007033/android-how-to-stretch-vertically-one-row-in-tablelayout): Make sure your TableLayout has its `layout_height` set to `match_parent` and give alll your rows a `layout_weight="1.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [TableLayout tutorial](http://d.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html)?

In the simplest way possible, you could have "empty" `TextView`s in each `TableRow`. By empty I mean having the `android:text=""`.