# How to stretch vertically one row in TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to stretch vertically one row in TableLayout.

For example:

The TableLayout have four rows (height and width is match_parent)

**ROW-1, ROW-2, ROW-4** have same height.

**ROW-3** - strechted vertically

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure your TableLayout has its layout_height set to `match_parent` and give your row 3 a `layout_weight="1.0"`.

Answer (score -3):

vertically is a column. If you have a row with 2 columns in the top and a row following that, then that row will also have 2 columns. Probably that is why 4 is not stretching vertically because of the rows above.
what you need to do is:
`android:stretchColumns ="*"`
This will stretch the column that is required making the row4 free of the rows above it.
See if it gives correct results.

Comment: "stretch vertically" means "stretch along the vertical axis", that is, make the rows higher".